# Can I programmatically instruct parsleyJS to ignore a validation group?

Tags: javascript, forms, parsley.js

I have a two step form that is validated with ParsleyJS.

The second step is a credit card details form. However, this is only required if a certain option is selected in part one of the form. It is possible to toggle between free and paid accounts.

How can I tell Parsley to ignore validation for the second group of inputs in my js?

Here is the relevant snippet

```
    var free = package.data('package-cost') * 1 <= 0;
    //Validate the step we are on
    if ($('form.register-form').parsley().validate($('.reg-step.active').data('parsley-group'))) {
        var form = $(this);
        if(free){
            //Submit free registration - I need to ignore validation of group 'step2' in here before submitting
            form.get(0).submit();
        }
        else{
            // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
            form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
            // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a select field, add a change event handler to your select field, when that is selected, set the data-attribute of the fields you dont want to validate , like so

```
$(yourselect).on('change', function() {
  if (this.value == 'your-value-where-validation-shouldnt-be-done')
   $('your-form-step-2-fields').data('parsley-excluded',true);
});
```